# How to center elements in the BoxLayout using center of the element?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout, center

I use `outputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` and then I add elements (for example JLabels, JButtons) to the `outputPanel`. For example: `outputPanel.add(submitButton);`.

I see that all added elements are "centered". It is good, because I do want my elements to be in the center. When I write "center" I mean "equal distance from left and right". But the problem is that the left part of the element is put into the center. And I want to have center of elements to be put into the center. How can I get this behavior?

Comment: I had a similar problem and found that instead of using `BoxLayout` , `FlowLayout` worked better and was easier to center align objects within it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using `myLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);`. It works with `JLabel`, `JButton` and `JRadioButton`.

Comment: I tried that and noticed that all items had to have applied setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT) to the same value of CENTER_ALIGNMENT. Applying it only to one JButton did not help. Also setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER) did not help at all.  Hope this is of a help to you.

Comment: While it works with `JLabel` or `JCombobox`es individually, it doesn't work when combining those.

Comment: I think setAlignmentX expects float, not enum - https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX(float)

Answer (score 6):

So far the best method I've encountered that works with **every** type of component:
1. Create a new **JPanel**:

`JPanel helperPanel = new JPanel();`
2. Add the component (in this example `submitButton`) you wish to center horizontally to the JPanel :

`helperPanel.add(submitButton);`
3. Add the panel to your original panel (the one with the BoxLayout):
`outerPanel.add(helperPanel);`

That's it!
You could also set a *maximum size*  on the `helperPanel` if you don't want the BoxLayout of the `outerPanel` to expand it.
If you're wondering why this works: the implicit layout manager of a JPanel is FlowLayout, which centers your elements automatically.

Comment: I would instantiate the `helperPanel` with a `new Borderlayout()`, otherwise the components will be cut off when using the *maximum size* trick.